# Generic type within Action?

Tags: c#

Action construct is generic but can that support generic type inside it?

The code snippet shown below is what I'm trying to achieve.

I'm aware of that there are other ways to do it but I am curious whether it can be achieved within an Action construct.

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    Action<int> Initialize = //<T> and where T is all that stuff
    (index) =>
    {
        T obj = new T();
        obj.Initialize(index);
        obj.DoWork();
    };

    Initialize<TypeA>(1);
    Initialize<TypeB>(2);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, basically - or at least, not within a single instance of an `Action` - a single instance is inherently closed in terms of generics. Obviously you could use a regular generic method `Initialize<T>`. If you *need* a single `Action`, then it might need to take the type as a parameter:

```
Action<Type, int> init = (type, index) => {
    ISomeInterface obj = (ISomeInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    obj.Initialize();
    obj.DoWork();
};
init(typeof(TypeA), 1);
init(typeof(TypeB), 2);
```

Otherwise:

```
void Initialize<T>(int index) where T : new(), ISomeInterface {
    T obj = new T();
    obj.Initialize();
    obj.DoWork();
}
void SomeMethod() {
    Initialize<TypeA>(1);
    Initialize<TypeB>(2);
}
```

You can create `Action<int>` delegates to represent **separately** `Initialize<TypeA>(int)` and `Initialize<TypeB>(int)`, but not both at the same time, and not the open `Initialize<T>(int)`.